If I am using an allow_listed_jwts table, why would it be a bad idea to use the tables integer primary key for the JTI?
I was looking at the Allowlist section of the docs for devise-jwt and I was wondering what the practical drawback is of using the primary key of the table for the JTI instead of a random value and dedicated string column?
If you are adding a record for every JWT issued, using the primary key would be guaranteed to be unique and shorter and faster to index, however it would be auto-incrementing and guessable. Is the ability to guess a JTI a serious concern? What would an exploit look like if your JTI is a simple incrementing value provided your JWT is signed with something like RS256 (or better) and includes other claims such as IAT, ISS, AUD and EXP?
From the docs:
def change
  create_table :allowlisted_jwts do |t|
    t.string :jti, null: false #<-- what makes this better than the table's PKEY?
    t.string :aud
    # If you want to leverage the `aud` claim, add to it a `NOT NULL` constraint:
    # t.string :aud, null: false
    t.datetime :exp, null: false
    t.references :your_user_table, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade }, null: false
  end

  add_index :allowlisted_jwts, :jti, unique: true
end


There is nothing in the spec that suggests using a primary key would be an issue, other than the fact that the jti claim must be a String. That being said the devise-jwt gem does rely on this column existing in the table when using these strategies as it both generates this value into the jti column (using a UUID) and checks this column for the value to determine revocation. That being said the jti claim is intended to act as a nonce, so what the gem does is revoke it by way of update. Using a primary_key this would likely need to be a delete.

Indeed, JTI Matcher strategy does that, however the AllowList strategy does delete the row.
https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/blob/3a0ade4bdcc9e23ff407f157ea59863da8b12279/lib/devise/jwt/revocation_strategies/allowlist.rb#L34C1-L38C1
